# Display suite, two layouts for the same node?

Tags: blocks, display-suite

I'm using display suite with [nodeblock](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeblock) and I'd like to have a different layout for the block than the main page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using different view modes.

1. On the content type edit page (eg. admin/structure/types/manage/page) you can set a default view mode for node blocks of that content type.
2. On the content type manage display page (eg. admin/structure/types/manage/page/display) configure the full content display mode (or default if you haven't enabled the full content mode) the way you want the full pages to display and configure the view mode you specified in step 1 the way you want the blocks to display.
3. You mention display suite in your question. You can also create additional view modes using display suite (admin/structure/ds/view_modes)